# V8 Callback, with Number instead of String

Tags: c++, node.js, pointers, v8, node.js-addon

Passing an argument from Node.js to the C++ function, and returning the result to Node.js via a callback function.

Following the [Node.js Addons Callback example](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_callbacks), the example has been modified to involve a Number instead of a String.

Here's the example codeset from the Node.js Addons:

```
Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
const unsigned argc = 1;
Local<Value> argv[argc] = { String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello world") };
cb->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

And here's the modified codeset, where value is a Number from a position in an Array:

```
Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[1]);
const unsigned argc = 2;
Local<Value> argv[argc] = {Number::New(isolate, value)};
cb->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

Comment: where is the segfault happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you define an array of size 2 for your arguments, you call the callback function passing arg count as 2 as well, but your initialize your array to a single value. Either change `argc = 1`, or initialize 2 values in the `argv` array.